# Nintex Regular Expression - Matching Surname, Firstname

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

Trying to extract a group of text using regular expression functionality within Nintex Workflow.

Original String:

```
Bishop-Miller, David (EM MS SUS OPS-ULT BI)
```

Output Required:

```
Bishop-Miller, David
```

Also want it to capture peoples names that might have hyphens or apostrophes and without the leading space.

I was trying this regex:

```
^([^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)
```

It does not work if the string is:

```
Bishop Miller, David (EM MS SUS OPS-ULT BI)
```

How would I amend the regex to fit this requirement?

Comment: What is your *problem*? Please share the pattern you tried and what type of action you are using. Are you just trying to remove all text inside last parentheses?

Comment: I was trying this: ^([^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)

Comment: So, what is the problem?  [Look here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5b%5e+%5d%2b%5b+%5d%5b%5e+%5d%2b%29&i=Bishop-Miller%2c+David+%28EM+MS+SUS+OPS-ULT+BI%29), it is working.

Comment: What if the string is: Bishop Miller, David (EM MS SUS OPS-ULT BI). How would i amend the regex to fit this requirement also.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex to match a substring between any leading whitespaces and the last non-whitespace char before the open parenthesis `(`:

```
(?<=^\s*)[^(]*[^\s(]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cs*%29%5B%5E%28%5D*%5B%5E%5Cs%28%5D&i=Bishop-Miller%2C%20David%20%28EM%20MS%20SUS%20OPS-ULT%20BI%29%0D%0ABishop%20Miller%2C%20David%20%28EM%20MS%20SUS%20OPS-ULT%20BI%29&o=m).

**Details**

- `(?<=^\s*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with 0+ whitespaces at the start of string
- `[^(]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(`
- `[^\s(]` - a char other than `(` and whitespace.

Use it with the *Extract* Operation.